# What could this extra 50ms latency be on my unbound DNS resolving server (Fedora)?

Tags: domain-name-system, fedora, latency, dnssec, unbound

I have a discrepancy in query latency. It's not a problem, it's just strange enough to worry me.

- Client machine (Fedora 18) runs unbound-1.4.19-1.fc18.x86_64.
- Server machine (Debian 7 testing) runs unbound 1.4.17-2.

Both are connected to the same home router.  However the server can resolve uncached queries almost twice as fast.  This wasn't what I expected at all!  The server is a 1Ghz ARM (sheevaplug), and the client machine is a 2.1Ghz Intel Core Duo.

Both instances validate DNSSEC.  They return SERVFAIL for www.dnssec-failed.org.  Both are configured to use the same upstream DNS caches from my ISP.

All I can think of so far is some issue with NAT.  The router is configured with the server as "default DMZ", i.e. it gets any packets no-one else is claiming, which is how I run public services like SSH and bittorrent :).  Or... maybe minor-version-19 is validating more strictly than minor-version-17, in some way?

Test methodology: resolution of 10 non-existent sub-domains of .de.  (Should cause ISP cache misses).  The .de. TLD is pre-loaded by querying yahoo.

From client side

```
$ for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do sudo unbound-control reload; (dig yahoo.de.; dig twitter$i.de.) | grep Query; done

Result - mean 120ms, stddev 60ms
```

From server side

```
$ for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do sudo unbound-control reload; (dig yahoo.de.; dig aldi$i.de. ) | grep Query; done

Result - mean 70ms, stddev 50ms
```

I know, the test doesn't look great, and my statistics may not be overwhelming evidence.  But I tried it a few more times, and it's not looking any different.

Answer (score 3):

Ah!  I just diffed the unbound.conf between the two computers.  It seems that Fedora turns on the option below.  Turning it off gets rid of the additional latency on the Fedora machine.

```
    # Harden the referral path by performing additional queries for
    # infrastructure data.  Validates the replies (if possible).
    # Default off, because the lookups burden the server.  Experimental
    # implementation of draft-wijngaards-dnsext-resolver-side-mitigation.
    harden-referral-path: yes
```

I'll have to look this up and decide whether I want to use it :).

Link: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-wijngaards-dnsext-resolver-side-mitigation/